# Low Resolution KML GroundOverlay

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a problem that has been driving me crazy for two days.

We have a Google Maps app that pulls in a KML file to display historical maps as image overlays. Around last week, our app started showing very blurry images that were pulled from googleusercontent servers not our own. What's even more puzzling is that the images in Google's cache are not the same size as the ones on my server -- they're three times smaller.

I'm not having any luck forcing Google to not use the version of the file in their cache. When I change the file's name or directory, I'll get a 404 error from the googleusercontent url, but it will not load the actual link that is being referenced.

Here is an example KML file (exported from Google Earth). The image is in the same directory as the KML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"  xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<GroundOverlay>
    <name>panel1</name>
    <Icon>
            <href>panel1.png</href>
            <viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>
    </Icon>
    <LatLonBox>
            <north>37.5422476694301</north>
            <south>37.53370251727466</south>
            <east>-77.43246990568036</east>
            <west>-77.44384562932868</west>
    </LatLonBox>
</GroundOverlay>
</kml>
```

Here is the call that I am making to load the KMLOverlay on my map.

```
this.GOOGLE_MAP = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('richmond_map'),{
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(<lat_value>, <lng_value>),
        zoom:16,
        streetView: new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama($('#street')[0],{disableDefaultUI: true})
    }); 

    var d = new Date();
    this.OVERLAY = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url: <url_to_KML_file>, clickable: false, map: this.GOOGLE_MAP, preserveViewport: true, zIndex:2 });
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem should be fixed now - see [Google Maps API issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7733) for a working example.